# SWT - change Column width without changing Table width

Tags: java, swt

I'm using a GridLayout...

On designing the look, I had a SWT table that is supposed to fit nicely (aesthetically) before I put in data.

For the data to show, I have to pack() each column

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++){
>      table.getColumn(i).pack();
> }
> ```

but doing so will expand the table's width, sometimes pushing other controls away or just making the table wider than it should be.

I need to keep this shell the same size as it is, so changing the shell's size is not an option.

How do I stop the table from expanding with the column widths?

---

Note: I WANT the scroll bars to come out instead. But just putting in the option to do so

> ```
> new Table(myShell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL)
> ```

didn't help my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GridData.widthHint` and `GridData.heightHint` to force a certain width/height of the `Table`. This way, it will not increase/decrease in size if it's content changes:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    final GridData data = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.BEGINNING, false, false);
    data.widthHint = 200;
    data.heightHint = 200;
    table.setLayoutData(data);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        TableColumn col = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        col.setText("C" + i);
        col.pack();
    }

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Fill table");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

                for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++)
                {
                    item.setText(j, "Item " + i + "," + j);
                }
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++)
            {
                table.getColumn(j).pack();
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 300);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Before adding the data:

[image]

After adding the data:

[image]

---

Keep in mind that it isn't good practice to force certain sizes on components. In your case, where the `Shell` itself is fixed to a certain size, I guess it's ok to do so.

Comment: First time using hints... Works wonderfully!

Though, to be honest, I didn't have a fixed size for the table (it was set up automatically), I guess it's time to set one.

Thank you.